# Dynamic image button is not displaying images in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Image button is receiving path of image from database but it not displaying it in image button.Instead of showing images in it webpage it is showing  submit query text.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        generateCategory();
    }

 public void generateCategory()
        {
            List<string> liCat = category();
            for(int i=0;i<category().Count; i++)
            {
                //HtmlAnchor ha = new HtmlAnchor();
                ImageButton imCat = new ImageButton();
                imCat.ID = "ImageCat" + i.ToString();
               // imCat.AlternateText = liCat[i].ToString();
                imCat.ImageUrl = liCat[i].ToString();
                //imCat.Attributes.Add("Class",);
                imCat.CssClass = "iMageButton";
                //ha.Controls.Add(imCat);
                panelControl.Controls.Add(imCat);
            }
        }
        public List<string> category()
        {
            List<string> catList = new List<string>();
            string query = "select Images from Category";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                  //  catList.Add(rdr["CategoryName"].ToString());
                    catList.Add(rdr["Images"].ToString());
                }
            }
            return catList;
        }[Image path in imCat.ImageUrl ][1]
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `liCat[i]`? Debug that first.

Comment: Images path is showing like this in imCat.ImageUrl :       F:\\OnlinePOS\\OnlinePOS\\StyleSheets\\images\\3.png     and liCat[i] containing the index of data in list.

Comment: that is not gonna work. You need the relative path! `/images/3.png`

Comment: but it is getting path like this.

Comment: Then you need to store only the image names, not the complete path.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I done it.